# Converting a number from base 10 to another base in clojure

Tags: clojure, decimal

I am supposed to write a function of 2 arguments, that converts the first number from base `10` to base `b`. The returned value should be a collection.

I tried using format but I don't know how to use it if `b` is `2,9,0` etc..

```
(defn f[x y]
   (cond
     (= y 8)(format "octal %o" x)
     (= y 16)(format "hex %x" x)
     (= y 10)(format "decimal %d" x) 
     :else 0))
```

Comment: 'returned value should be a collection' - what should it contain?

Comment: Please give an example of the output required. I guess you want a sequence of digits, but in what order?

Answer (score 7):

Given that this is not some kind of exercise where you have to
do the conversion manually, you can use Java's `Integer.toString`

e.g.

```
user> (Integer/toString 123456 13) ;; 123456 in base 13
"44268"
```

As for the sequence part you can just `(seq (Integer/toString numb base)`
However, this will return the chars (0-9 and a-z). You'll probably
want a lookup function in order to get the numbers.

Also check [toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int,%20int%29) documentation for allowed
radices.

If on the other hand the requirement is that you convert manually 
then [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111150/changing-a-number-between-arbitrary-bases) MO article is probably a good start.

Comment: from what I can tell, `(Integer/toString ...)` only works up to base 36 (10 numerals + 26 letters)

Answer (score 3):

Here is mine pure Clojure solution:

```
(def charset "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")

(def num->char
  (into {} (map-indexed vector charset)))

(def char->num
  (into {} (map-indexed (comp vec reverse vector) charset)))

(def base (count charset))

(def divmod (juxt quot rem))

(defn exp [x n]
  (loop [acc 1 n n]
    (if (zero? n) acc
        (recur (* x acc) (dec n)))))

(defn encode [n]
  (loop [n n a ""]
    (let [[div mod] (divmod n base)]
      (if (zero? div)
        (str (get num->char mod) a)
        (recur div (str (get num->char mod) a))))))

(defn decode-pair [idx chr]
  (* (get char->num chr)
     (exp base idx)))

(def sum (partial reduce +))

(defn decode [s]
  (sum (map-indexed decode-pair (reverse s))))
```

Usage:

```
(encode 1000000000)
15FTGg

(decode "15FTGg")
1000000000

(-> 1000 encode decode (= 1000))
true
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(defn to-digits
  [n b]
  (loop [n n
         digits ()]
    (if (pos? n)
      (recur (quot n b)
             (conj digits (mod n b)))
      digits)))
```

Comment: When I try `(to-digits 1000 16)`, it throws exception on me! `NumberFormatException For input string: "e"` (Java Solution)

Comment: when i try (to-digits 110 16) i dont get 6 E in result it shows (6 14)

Comment: That is true. Decimals are the most generic representation of the single digits.

Comment: E. g. if you eval `(to-digits 100 1000)` what symbol would you like instead of 100 in `(100)`. If you need a specific representation on the result of algorithm, you should write a specific representation algorithm.

Comment: When I try `(to-digits 0 2)` the result is `()`.

Answer (score 2):

The following functions will do the conversion, casting to java's BigInteger so it will also work for integer values over `Integer/MAX_VALUE` (2147483647)

```
(defn to-radix
  [int r]
  (.toString (biginteger int) r))

(to-radix 255 2)
=> "11111111"

(defn from-radix
  [str r]
  (BigInteger. str r)

(from-radix "11111111" 2)
=> 255
```

Strings can be considered a collection of characters. Map, filter, reduce etc. will call `seq` to traverse it. In other cases you can just call `seq` yourself.

```
(seq (to-radix 255 2))
=> (\1 \1 \1 \1 \1 \1 \1 \1)
```